# How to make cellediting cells wider than the actual column?

Tags: extjs, tablecelleditor

Very simple scenario: I want to have a small grid for a good overview. But when clicking in a cell the editor should have a higher width than the actual column.

Example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/reg&view/editor

I tried to specify the width and I tried to add it in the afterrender. Width is always exactly as wide as the column. Same problem with textareas.

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    width: 500,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (field) {
            field.setWidth(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this should be easy but I couldn't find a way to accomplish that. I can specify the height on a textarea but the width isn't considered.

Comment: Hey can you please tell precisely how column will look after editor is displayed.Please post some image.

Comment: If you click in the company cell I expect the editors textfield be bigger. It would overlapp the price column to the right so I can enter more text. Right now the companys column with is width: 160. I want the textfield editor cell to be 240 for example.

Comment: I have solved this issue except for first time as text field is not rendered initially.After it is rendered I have set its width in beforeedit event.If you want solution I can paste here.

Comment: if you have a solution feel free to post it. would be great to see an approach. In theory this should be easy but the framework seem to have some restrictions that make those things hard for no reason..

Answer (score 1):

Check below fiddle.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/27bv&view/editor
Here I have done change for setting width of table node in which cell editor is rendered by `Ext.get(Ext.get(Ext.query('div.x-grid-editor')[0]).dom.childNodes[0]).setWidth(300)`.

This approach is having **one limitation**- for first time width is not getting set as in beforeedit event we do not get instance of editor.If we get this instance we can apply similar logic for setting editor's width.
please check if it could solve your issue or not.Also let me know for any changes.
Note: I have impl. this thing for first column only.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - it helped me to figure out how it's gonna work. I use my afterrender method - I just had the wrong element to work with.. instead of using "field" I have to get the exact dom element. Ext.get(field.el.dom.childNodes[1]).setWidth(500) - index is 1 cause 0 is the label..

Comment: Even easier: field.bodyEl.setWidth(500); inside the afterrender.. oh and BTW. this will only work for textarea fields. I will add an answer when I figured out the complete solution for simple textfields as well but it shouldn't be a big deal..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out a solution which is pretty close to mine.

```
afterrender: function (field) {
  field.bodyEl.setWidth(500);
}
```

This works for textareas and textfields with Ext version 5. I found out that in my fiddle I also used the wrong Ext version. Seems not to work with Ext 4.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/27cc&view/editor

Comment: Both of our solutions combined gives complete result.